# Splitting Data in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, oop, attributes

it does not work. I want to split data as in code in lines attribute.

```
class movie_analyzer:
    def __init__(self,s):
        for c in punctuation:
            import re

            moviefile = open(s, encoding = "latin-1")
            movielist = []
            movies = moviefile.readlines()
  
    def lines(movies):
        for movie in movies:
                if len(movie.strip().split("::")) == 4:
                    a = movie.strip().split("::")
                    movielist.append(a)

        return(movielist)

movie = movie_analyzer("movies-modified.dat")

movie.lines
```

It returns that:

[image]

Comment: There seems to be little reason for this to be a class, rather than a simple function.

Answer (score 0):

To call a function you use `movie.lines()` along with the argument. What you are doing is just accessing the method declaration. Also, make sure you use self as argument in method definitions and save the parameters you want your Object to have. And it is usually a good practice to keep your imports at the head of the file.

```
import re

class movie_analyzer:
    def __init__(self,s):
        for c in punctuation:    
            moviefile = open(s, encoding = "latin-1")
            self.movielist = []
            self.movies = moviefile.readlines()

    @property
    def lines(self):
        for movie in self.movies:
                if len(movie.strip().split("::")) == 4:
                    a = movie.strip().split("::")
                    self.movielist.append(a)

        return self.movielist

movie = movie_analyzer("movies-modified.dat")

movie.lines()
```

Comment: Thank you, it runs like this. But i want to run it as movie.lines. How should I change the code?

Comment: I edited bearing in mind the answer given by @gmdev . Let me know if it works, and, if so, please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@property` decorator to be able to access the result of the method as a property. See this very simple example of how this decorator might be used:

```
import random

class Randomizer:
    def __init__(self, lower, upper):
        self.lower = lower
        self.upper = upper
    
    @property
    def rand_num(self):
        return random.randint(self.lower, self.upper)
```

Then, you can access it like so:

```
>>> randomizer = Randomizer(0, 10)
>>> randomizer.rand_num
5
>>> randomizer.rand_num
7
>>> randomizer.rand_num
3
```

Obviously, this is a useless example; however, you can take this logic and apply it to your situation.

Also, one more thing: you are not passing `self` to `lines`. You pass `movies`, which is unneeded because you can just access it using `self.movies`. However, if you want to access those variables using `self` you have to set (in your `__init__` method):

```
self.movielist = []
self.movies = moviefile.readlines()
```