# Create a class attribute as dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I have a .dat file. I am creatting a class which takes file name as an input. I have below code.But it gives an error. I want to return it as dictionary. Actually, my main problem here, select 2nd and 3rd values.

```
import re

class movie_analyzer:

    def __init__(self,s):


            self.genre_dict=open(s, encoding="latin-1").read().split('\n')

            self.genre_dict=dict(x.split('::')[1:2] for x in self.genre_dict)


movie=movie_analyzer("movies.dat")

movie.genre_dict
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp3nZ.png)

movies.dat looks like this:

```
Movies = ["1::Toy Story::Animation|Children's|Comedy::1995\n",

"2::Jumanji::Adventure|Children's|Fantasy::1995\n",

'3::Grumpier Old Men::Comedy|Romance::1995\n',

'4::Waiting to Exhale::Comedy|Drama::1995\n',

'5::Father of the Bride Part II::Comedy::1995\n']
```

Expected result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGJbO.png)

Comment: The error in the first image does not correspond to the code you posted. The `[1:2]` part is missing. I think it should be `[0:2]` or just `[:2]` by the way.

Comment: Also please don't post output as images; it makes it hard to read and impossible to search. Just copy and paste it into your question and format it as code.

Comment: How many times you are going to ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65252992/how-to-create-class-with-an-input-in-python)?

Comment: But, i need to select 2nd and 3rd values. If I use [0:2] it gives first 3 values.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to focus on one issue. Are you asking how to create such a class, how to create such a dictionary, or how to select 2nd and 3rd values?

Answer (score 0):

For creating the required dictionary use:

```
self.genre_dict={x.split('::')[1] : x.split('::')[2] for x in self.genre_dict}
```

Comment: Thank you!I have tried. It gives list index out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using panda:

```
movies = ["1::Toy Story::Animation|Children's|Comedy::1995\n",
"2::Jumanji::Adventure|Children's|Fantasy::1995\n",
'3::Grumpier Old Men::Comedy|Romance::1995\n',
'4::Waiting to Exhale::Comedy|Drama::1995\n',
'5::Father of the Bride Part II::Comedy::1995\n']


df = pd.DataFrame( data = movies , columns = ['movies'])
#extract the movie name
df['movie_name'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['movies'].split('::')[1] , axis=1)
#extract the movie data
df['movie_data'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['movies'].split('::')[2] , axis=1)

#convert the dataframe into dict with as movie_name.
print(df.set_index('movie_name')['movie_data'].to_dict())
```

Results into

```
{'Toy Story': "Animation|Children's|Comedy", 'Jumanji': "Adventure|Children's|Fantasy", 'Grumpier Old Men': 'Comedy|Romance', 'Waiting to Exhale': 'Comedy|Drama', 'Father of the Bride Part II': 'Comedy'}
```